# Fullcalendar : columns are destroyed in agendaWeek view if some html is added and too many events are rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce, fullcalendar, visualforce

I am using fullcalendar on a Visualforce page from Salesforce.

I want to add a small button `+` on each day of the `agendaDay`, `agendaWeek` and `Month views` (at the top of the column, in the `All day` line).

It works fine on `Month` and `agendaDay` views. But when it comes to the `agendaWeek` view, it works fine only if there are a few events in the all day line. If there are enough events to trigger the `+3 more` or `+X more`, events and `+` buttons are split, and the whole table is broken because it doubles the number of columns (7 columns with events only, and 7 columns with the button only).

It seems there is a change occuring in the CSS of the table when this "+X more" appears, but I don't know how to detect it and adapt my code.

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/9ywmd1gf/8/) shows the problem. (see all-day events in agenda-view).

Comment: Can you give the reproducing code or make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) test case?

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle of the initialisation of Fullcalendar : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p653ju48/)
My problem is what i use between lines 53 and 87.

Comment: So [here](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/9ywmd1gf/4/) is a running version of the fiddle. Had to butcher it a bit to get it to run (some functions aren't included). But the `agendaWeek` view in FC never gives you a `+X more` option so I can't reproduce the problem. Are you using an old version of FC or something?

Comment: I am using jquery 1.11.1 and fullcalendar 2.3.1.
Also, I edited your JSFiddle, and managed to reproduce my problem.
I added "allDay:true" to the events you created. For 5 events, the table is still fine, but when I add a sixth one, the table is destroyed.
Example with 5 events here : [5events](http://jsfiddle.net/9ywmd1gf/5/)
Example with 6 events here : [6events](http://jsfiddle.net/9ywmd1gf/7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems to be a bug in FC (or unsupported).

FullCalendar renders the `allDay` events with a weird table structure. You can take a look at it with your browser's dev tools.

One of the things it does is create the top row of the `allDay` events table (`.fc-day-grid .fc-content-skeleton table`) with `rowspan=maxNumOfEventsDuringWeek` on each column. The problem is it uses the actual number of events and not number of *visible* events.

So if you have 3 events, it sets `rowspan=3`, which works. But if you have 10 events, it sets `rowspan=10` even though only 4 are visible when `eventLimit` is on.

This doesn't normally cause a problem, but when you added another row to the table, the rows above pushed it off to the side and "broke it".

**Possible Fix**

If you are really attached to your current code, you could add some code to "fix" the `rowspan`. I don't recommend this as it's too hacky and won't be stable.

But basically, you would:

- Count the number of visible events
- Change the `rowspan` attributes on each column of the first row

**Better alternative**

Instead of adding a row to the table, let's just add an absolutely positioned link. Here's the `eventAfterRender` function (I've shortened it too):

```
eventAfterAllRender: function (view) {
    var addPlusToDay = function (dayOfWeek) { // Adds a button to a day number (1 through 7)
        var day = moment(view.start).add(dayOfWeek, 'd');
        var plus = j$('<a href="/path/file.jsp?date=' + day.format('L') +
                    '" target="_parent" class="addLink"' +
                     ' style="display: block; position:absolute; bottom:0px;">'+
                     '<img src="/image/s.png" alt="Ajouter un événement - ' + day.format('L') +
                     '" class="addNewEventIcon" title="Ajouter un événement - ' + day.format('L') +
                     '" style="margin-right:0px;"></a>');
        plus.appendTo(j$('#calendar .fc-day-grid .fc-content-skeleton tbody tr:first td:not(.fc-axis)').get(dayOfWeek));
    }
    if (view.name == 'agendaWeek') {
        var days = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
        $.each(days, addPlusToDay);
    }
    if (view.name == 'agendaDay') {
        addPlusToDay(0);
        var dateParam = view.start;
        generateActivitiesTable(dateParam, 'dayView');*/
    }
}
```

And here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/9ywmd1gf/11/).

Also note the CSS in the demo, it fixes a couple of formatting problems.

Comment: I agree with you about the possible fix, it may not be stable enough. Also, I already had a look about this "weird table structure" but could not get it fixed.
I implemented your alternative code and it works perfectly at the moment. 
You also improved it a lot (from 50 to 20 lines).
So thank you for your work and your time. I will keep you informed here if I got some issues with your work, but I doubt I will ! =)